# Running totals to work throughout classes in java?

Tags: java, cumulative-sum

I am current writing a program that includes a test. When the user clicks submit it either prints out correct or incorrect and then goes to a different class. As well as doing this i want if the answer is correct to add 1 to a variable.

The thing i can't work out is how to do this in different classes since 1 or 0 will need to be added for everything question which are saved in different classes but in the same project.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason that each question is a separate class? It seems that you could have a single Question class which hold instance variables, such as

```
public class Question{
    private String text; //the question itself
    private String[] choices; //the choices if this is a multiple-choice question
    private int answer; //the index in choices that is the correct answer

    //constructor, accessors, mutators

    public String toString(){
        String retval = this.text+"\n";
        for(int x=0;x<choices.length;x++){
            char c = 'a'+x; //this will give characters going alphabetically from 'a'
            retval+=c+") "+choices[x]+"\n";
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Then you could have a Test class with the main method.

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Question[] questions = {
            new Question("What is 1+1?", new String[]{"2", "3", "4"}, 0),
            //other questions here
        }

        int total=0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(Question q: questions){
            System.out.println(q.toString());
            int ans = input.nextLine().charAt(0)-'a';
            if(q.getAnswer()==ans){
                total++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does this sort of do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This counter does not have a context within each of the individual classes. It only has context within the code you have managing these tests you are running. So, within this manager class, you have one variable that you increment each time a test completes and you detect it to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You want a different class with a public final static class and variable.

Something like this:

```
public class Counter {
    private static int count=0;
    public static int add() {
        return count++;
    }
}
```

You may want a getter as well.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever class has a reference to the questions should loop through them and sum up a total of correct questions.  If your questions don't inherit from the same class create an interface named Question that has a isAnswerRight() method that you can call, or something similar.